# crontab not running node.js

Tags: node.js, cron

I have configured a crontab -e to run every 1 minute. I have tested it to run via terminate with success. When running in crontab it doesn't progress.

`which node: /usr/bin/node`

`user: ubuntu`

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/git/web3-tools/ && /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/git/web3-tools/src/scripts/crowdsale/set-crowdsale-rate.script.js
```

I feel it has something to do with Node_Modules and cron launching from the root directory.

Any help would be great.

Comment: you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I created a `set-rate.sh` file using: `touch set-rate.sh`
2. `chmod +x set-rate.sh` - make it executable
3. `NODEPATH=$(which node)
   export NODE_ENV="production"
   PROCESS="$NODEPATH /home/ubuntu/git/web3-tools/src/scripts/crowdsale/set-crowdsale-rate.script.js"
   cd /home/ubuntu/git/web3-tools/
   $PROCESS`

NOTE: `cd` into the directory where you interact with your `node_modules`. Add the absolute node path.

4. crontab -e `* * * * * /home/ubuntu/set-rate.sh >> /tmp/cron-log.txt 2>&1` NOTE add a space at the end of the file
   `
   To help debug my issue - I added a log to the cron job.